# Abstract model in Django with ForeignKey doesn't inherit as expected

Tags: python, django, django-models, error-handling

When attempting to execute `makemigrations` in my Django application, I encounter errors related to circular references. I have defined an abstract class *A* that inherits from models.Model, and two child classes *B* and *C*. However, it seems I am making mistakes with the relationships between these classes. Here is the relevant code:

```
class A(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    
    z = models.ForeignKey(Z, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="relateds")


class B(A):
    algo = models.CharField(max_length=32, default="")


class C(A):
    foo = IntegerField()
```

I am facing the following error:

> z.B.z: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'z.B.z' clashes with reverse query name for 'z.C.z'.

Any help or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because you have two real models `B` and `C`, each with a `ForeignKey` to `Z`, and that `Z` thus can not have both with the *same* value for [**`related_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). Why? Because the related name is the name of the relation in *reverse*. So from `Z` to `B` or `C`. So if you would query `my_z.relateds.all()`, then what model should it target? `B` or `C`?

You can resolve it by letting the `related_name=…` depend on the name of the class it is defined in, like:

```
class A(models.Model):
    z = models.ForeignKey(Z, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)ss')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

or with:

```
class A(models.Model):
    z = models.ForeignKey(Z, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_set')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

but that is just what Django does if you don't specify a related name yourself, which might be the best option:

```
class A(models.Model):
    z = models.ForeignKey(Z, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # 🖘 no related_name=…

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```